# Send data from servlet to cfm

Tags: servlets, coldfusion, cfml

I wan't to send data from HelloWorld servlet to index.cfm page. I use for output "#data#" But It is don't work(write "#data#"). How output data from java servlet to .cfm file and create a list with this data in cfm page, like in jsp: <% List data= (List)request.getAttribute("data"); %>

HelloWorld.java

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        request.setAttribute("data", "123");
        String url = "/cfm/index.cfm";
        request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

index.cfm

```
<html>
<head>
<title>This is a test CFM page calling a Servlet page</title>
</head>
<body>
<cfoutput> 
 <br> #data#<br> 
</cfoutput>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is cmf extension?

Comment: Could you please be more specific about what doesn't work?

Comment: Do you see anything in the response?  Do you see the "This is a test CFM page..." text?

Comment: Not cmf, .cfm-basic page in Coldfusion Server

Comment: Cfm page show me when I start servlet, but I want see '123' instead '#data#'

Comment: I see: "This is a test CFM page calling a Servlet page
#data# "

Comment: That is good.  It verifies that you are properly forwarding the request.  Thus this is probably a CFM issue in your app.  Have you verified that CFM is properly configured in this app (sorry to not be more specific but I have not worked with CFM)

Comment: From the code you posted, #data# looks to be an undefined variable in index.cfm.

Comment: And how define variable data=request from servlet and output it?

Comment: Can you try this:  Change "#data#" to "#Request.data#"

Comment: First you have to create a java HelloWorld object in ColdFusion.

Comment: Change "#data#" to "#Request.data#" and see: "This is a test CFM page calling a Servlet page #Request.data#"

Comment: This is old, but have you seen it: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-786c.html  If #data# is ouptut directly, that tells me the CFML servlet is not processing it.  You might need to forward to the "CfmServlet" or whatever it's called in your version of CF.  What version ARE you running?

Comment: I think this confirms that you app is not properly setup for CFM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all,
particularly EJK and Mark A Kruger:

I solve:`<cfoutput>#Request.data#</cfoutput>`

Comment: If the above works, then you were NOT using `cfoutput` tags like you said. Otherwise, CF would have thrown an "variable data is undefined ..." error, rather than displaying the text: *"This is a test CFM page calling a Servlet page #data# "* Glad [@EKJ was able to provide the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745865/send-data-from-servlet-to-cfm#comment43903375_27745865), but for next time .. please post the *actual* code you are using ;-)

Comment: (Oops.. sorry, EJK! I fat fingered your moniker.)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of the specifics of your servlet but here's a quick tutorial.

Your attribute will come as either URL or FORM params. CF actually separates these into 2 separate scopes. So you might try:

```
<cfoutput>#url.data#</cfoutput>
```

If it's coming in the form scope use:

```
<cfoutput>#form.data#</cfoutput>
```

Here's a couple other things you can try:

```
<cfdump var="#url#"/>

<cfdump var="#form#"/>

<cfdump var="#cgi#"/>
```

Each of these might give you clues as to how your data is arriving at the CF template.  Of course you will want to make sure it *is arriving* there - I see no HOST in your request. I'm assuming the servlet knows what the HOST and protocol should be.

-Mark